# How to make signed 64 bit integer using one signed integer and one unsigned integer on 32 bit processor

Tags: c

On 32 bit processor with 32 bit compiler I want to make a 64 bit signed integer  using one of each signed and unsigned integer. Without using any predefined macro or types.

Comment: Are you implementing the compiler in C? Don't you have `long long`?

Comment: Use `int64_t` with `<stdint.h>`

Comment: By the way, what *are* you doing? Are you creating a compiler? Are you creating a Linux device driver? And what does this have to do with memory alignment? Or the Arch Linux distribution? Don't spam with tags unrelated to your problem.

Comment: And what is your *actual* problem? Why do you need 64-bit integers? What is the *original* problem you want to solve by (possibly) implementing your own 64-bit arithmetic functionality? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)!

Comment: I want you to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

32-bit compilers will handle 64-bit numbers for you. So its unlikely you actually need this. But I'll bite. On the surface this is a pretty simple problem.

```
#include <stdint.h>

static inline int64_t make_int64(uint32_t low, int32_t high) {
    return (int64_t)((uint64_t)high << 32) | low;
}

static inline void split_int64(int64_t value, uint32_t *low, int32_t *high) {
    *low = value & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    *high = (int32_t)((uint32_t)(value >> 32));
}
```

But its always tricky/dangerous mixing signed and unsigned integers. Manually constructing an int also requires you to know how the processor formats them. We'll assume its 2s compliment little endian.

It would be helpful if you gave a full description of your requirements. For example the above example make_int64(0, -1) = -4294967296 but make_int64(1, -1) = -4294967295.

Comment: How do you encode `-1` using this scheme?  And `+1`?

Comment: I added a matching encoder for you @JonathanLeffler. All I'm doing is splitting a 64-bit in half. The only strange thing I'm doing is using cast to keep the CPU from sign extending. Of course this is only useful for storing/retrieving. If he wants to manipulate the split int in some way he'd have to worry about endian issues etc.